# how do i change my plot so the dots also vary by [-0.1:0.1] in the width

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In this code my dots in the plot vary in height in the interval `[-0.1;0.1]`, how do  i change my plot so the dots also vary by `[-0.1:0.1]` in the width?

grades is a NxM numpy array as a matrix, with the numbers `[-3,00,2,4,7,10,12]` random placed.

```
grades=grades[:,2:].T
# Changes so the dots vary i height
matrix = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,grades.shape)
plotGrades = grades + matrix
# this line is relevant for another plot
mean=np.array(np.mean(grades,axis=1)) 
assignment=np.arange(1,1 + np.size(mean))
plt.figure(2, figsize=(15,20))
plt.xticks(range(len(grades)+1))
plt.yticks([-3,00,2,4,7,10,12])
plt.plot(assignment,plotGrades,'b.')
# This line are relevant for another plot
plt.plot(assignment,mean)
plt.title("Grades per assignment")
plt.xlabel("Assignments")
plt.ylabel("Grades")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this should work :

```
grades=grades[:,2:].T
# Changes so the dots vary i height
matrix = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,grades.shape)
plotGrades = grades + matrix
# this line is relevant for another plot
mean=np.array(np.mean(grades,axis=1)) 
assignment=np.arange(1,1 + np.size(mean))
plt.figure(2, figsize=(15,20))
plt.xticks(range(len(grades)+1))
plt.yticks([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])

matrix2 = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,(assignment.shape[0],1))
assignment2=assignment+matrix2

plt.plot(assignment2,plotGrades,'b.')
# This line are relevant for another plot
plt.plot(assignment,mean)
plt.title("Grades per assignment")
plt.xlabel("Assignments")
plt.ylabel("Grades")
plt.hold
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The problem was that `assignment` size is `(3,)` and :

```
matrix2 = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,assignment.shape)
```

yields a 1D vector of size 3 with all the components equal to the same value. That is why you had the same value added everywhere.

Comment: Yup that worked!
but why does it works when i use shape[0],1 ?

Comment: Because this creates the tuple `(3,1)`. If you set the size of the vector to `(3,)`, it will return a vector of size 3 with the same value for each component. If you set the size at `(3,1)`, it looks basically the same but it sets the components independently. So you get a 1D vector of size 3 with (statistically) different values for each coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work if I understand correctly now:

```
grades=grades[:,2:].T
#**Changes so the dots vary i height**
matrix = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,grades.shape)
plotGrades = grades + matrix
#**this line is relevant for another plot**
mean=np.array(np.mean(grades,axis=1)) 
assignment=np.arange(1,1 + np.size(mean))
plt.figure(2, figsize=(15,20))
plt.xticks(range(len(grades)+1))
plt.yticks([-3,00,2,4,7,10,12])

matrix2 = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,assignment.shape)
assignment2=assignment+matrix2

plt.plot(assignment2,plotGrades,'b.')
#**This line are relevant for another plot**
plt.plot(assignment,mean)
plt.title("Grades per assignment")
plt.xlabel("Assignments")
plt.ylabel("Grades")
plt.show()
```

Comment: No it is explained here,  I have  done it for the y-coordante, but i cant figure out, how i can do it for the x-coordinat
"Each of the given grades marked by a dot. You must add a small random
number (between -0.1 and 0.1) to the x- and y-coordinates of each dot, to
be able tell apart the different dots which otherwise would be on top of each
other when more than one student has received the same grade in the same
assignment"

Comment: Ah, in that case, why not create a new independent matrix of random numbers that you add to "assignment" to create dispersion in x too

Comment: I already tried that, but it just add the same number to all the dots in the current line :/ which make sense because assigntment is just a list/vector, and not a matrix

Comment: if you use plot_assignment = assignment + np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,assignment.shape) should do what you want.

Comment: And then add the matrix to assignment? hmm i will try that

Comment: but i cant add a matrix to a vector

Comment: yes: all you need to do is create a new random matrix with shape consistent with what you will be adding it to (hence assignment.shape (1xM of randoms) instead of grades.shape (NxM of randoms))

Comment: I already tried that, but it just add the same number to all the dots in the current line :/ which make sense because assigntment is just a list/vector, and not a matrix